# adodb.recordset retrieves only partial blob data from sqlite3 database

Tags: vba, sqlite, blob, partial

I'm trying to retrieve some binary data stored in a sqlite3 database using vba in excel. It runs smoothly except that only partial blob data is retrieved. The blob is 11204 bytes long. The size of the returned recordset field is right. However, only the first 255 bytes contains valid value, following a bunch of 0s. And even more weird, there are a few valid bytes here and there in the vast ocean of 0s.
I used three different ways to retrieve data after a successful query: getrows(), rst.Fields().Value, and adoStream.Read(), all get the same results.

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & fileName & ";" 

query = "SELECT * FROM " & dataTable & ";"
rst.Open query, conn, 1, 1
data = rst.getrows()

Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
adoStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
adoStream.Open    
With rst
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    For i = 1 To .RecordCount
        data = rst.fields(dataField).value
        rst.Save adoStream, 0
        data = adoStream.Read(adoStream.Size)
    next i
end With
```

I tried some different databases and it's all the same.
Can anyone tell me what happens here?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're persisting the whole recordset to the stream?  Did you just want the blob field content instead?

Comment: Maybe try `adoStream.Write rst.fields(dataField).value`

Comment: I'm afraid the problem here is not about stream. I use stream as an alternative to retrieve blob after getrows() not having all the valid data. rst.Fields().Value doesn't behave properly in the first place - it has the right size (11204), but not all the data. @Tim Williams I want to get the blob field content only (all the fields in the table are blob). Tried your suggestion, but it doesn't do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For binary data, the [.AppendChunk and .GetChunk methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/appendchunk-and-getchunk-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15) are most appropriate. Something like this:

```
If rs.fields(dataField).ActualSize > 0 Then
  vntResult = rs.fields(dataField).GetChunk(rs.fields(dataField).ActualSize)
End If
```

Comment: When using GetChunk, I got an error: VBA Error-'Run-time error 3219-Operation is not allowed in this context'. I'm wondering if it has something to do with field.DefinedSize=255. @HelO'Ween

Comment: That's unfortunate. And it seems that's [a limitation of SQLite/SQLite's ODBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244270/storing-and-retrieving-large-strings-in-sqlite-with-ado-and-vbscript). I wasn't aware of that when posting my answer. Sorry about that. Back in the day, there was an amazing project called dhRichClient3 by Olaf Schmidt, including a SQlite wrapper. But it has since disappeared. [Archive.org has a snapshot of it](https://web.archive.org/web/20110724094433/http://www.thecommon.net/3.html), if you want to have a look.